# Weird Panel / Panel / PictureBox interaction

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2013, chess

I'm making a windows forms Chess app in visual studio 2013. As everyone knows, when a pawn reaches the last rank (row) it is promoted, becoming a stronger figure (a Rook, a Bishop, a Knight or a Queen). I'm doing that via a panel that appears on top of the board with buttons to select the figure. I don't want to use a message box. The following screenshot illustrates the problem I've ran into:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/LD8mi.png

The structure of the Board is ( **this is NOT the code** , i just use the syntax):

```
class Board : Panel //Contains Panel BoardPanel
{
    class Figure : PictureBox 
    Panel PanelPawnConversion;
    Panel BoardPanel //All the Figures and PanelPawnConversion are on this panel
                     // black and white squares are drawn there too.
}
```

PanelPawnConversion contains 2 buttons, it is initially invisible. It becomes visible when a Pawn needs to be promoted. Its backcolor is not transparent and it is also BringToFront() 'ed. I've ran out of ideas on how to fix this. I haven't provided the code because relevant parts are scattered all around it and, as I see it, don't explain more than I already did.

Comment: Why don't you use a modal dialog?

Comment: Transparency in WinForms is with respect to the parent **container** only.  If the panel is parented to the form, then it would appear to be transparent only with the **background** of the **form**.  If the panel **overlaps** any other **controls**, then the illusion of transparency disappears.  If you need finer control then you'll have to switch to WPF, which is a different paradigm altogether.  Another option is to physically **clip** the panel by modifying its `Region()` property so that it only contains the regions where the child buttons are (use `GraphicsPath` to build the `Region`).

Comment: Are you nesting controls, perhaps? How is the structure of the board? 64 panels or PBoxes?  Or 32 ?? @Idle: There seems to be no transparancy used, as far as I understand. - Why does the Panel only have two Buttons when there are 4 pieces to choose from..

Comment: @TaW everything is nested within the Board class, but PanelPawnConversion is on the BoardPanel. There are 32 PBoxes, containing images of figures. And It only has 2 buttons (Queen and Knight) because in my version getting stalemated is the same as getting checkmated, so underpromotion is useless. This is made for performance reasons, the app is not meant for humans, 2 chess engines will be battling trillions times so speed is critical. Actually, there is no checkmate either, the game ends when a King is captured. Same reasoning.

Comment: @Idle_Mind Sure, I do know how transparency works in WinForms, but the panel that's supposed to be on top has its background color not transparent. Only figures' backgrounds are transparent.

Comment: Ah, the pieces have a transparent background? That could explain a part of the image (the small grey areas on the pawns' squares). I would recommend to have two sets for each piece: On black and on  white squares to rule out the dreaded transparence errors. But the center pieces (Q & p) seem to sit on top of the panel.  Not sure why also not sure how you move them: By changing the location or by removing and re-adding them. Can you send them toBack for a test.

Comment: On a side note: I wonder why you do a visual representation with the obvious aim to move much faster than anybody could even see it, let alone follow..?

Comment: @TaW Because there would be different spectating options, such as pausing or moving with delays enough to follow the game or skipping a few turns. Also, the way I'm doing it, the chess engine will be adapting and learning game positions, losing/winning moves and stuff like that. ~140GB database. So visual representation is required for a human to play against the engine. It IS meant for humans trying to beat the machine after all the learning process, which happens without the visual representation.

Comment: @TaW having 2 sets of pieces won't help, because board coloring can be changed before the game. Having dynamically drawn bitmaps would, but those are really slow to process. And I'm changing location, not re-adding pieces, so it shouldn't mess up with the order of controls.

Comment: I don't understand. I meant two sets of images, ie 2 pawns 2 rooks, 2 knights, 2 bishops, 2 kings and 2 queens for each color, a total of 20 images, best all in an ImageList, switching the images when the square color changes..

Comment: @TaW I've meant that square color may change as a user wishes. He may want not black and white, but brown and yellow. Or cyan and green. I can't have images for all colors.

Comment: Ah. Well you __could__ by preparing them from one set of 10 transparent pngs right after the background colors are chosen..